# Apache htaccess Options +FollowSymLinks no longer works at hosting company Hostgator

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My site is hosted ar Hostgator. For several years rewrites in my .htaccess file worked perfectly. All of a sudden they stopped working. The directive in question is Options +FollowSymLinks directive in the htaccessfile.

This was what my htaccess file looked like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes

RewriteRule ^unit/([^/]+)?$ /unit/$1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^unit/([^/]+)/?$ /unit.php?unit=$1
RewriteRule ^unit/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /unit.php?unit=$1&category=$2
```

After days of troubleshooting, I found that if I remove the plus sign from in front of "FollowSymLinks", it works.

The directive now looks like this:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
```

I spoke to tech support at Hostgator, they have no clue why it no longer functions with the correct syntax, which includes the "+" sign.

The old htaccess file still works perfectly in my local development environment.
If I upload the htaccess file with the "+" plus sign, the redirects do not work. If I remove the "+" sign and upload the htaccess file, the redirects work.

I cant understand why the incorrect syntax functions and the correct syntax for the directive does not function.

I even used the syntax directly from the Hostgator support article!
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/general-help/apache-mod_rewrite-and-examples

Any insight would be appreciated. I also want to let you guys know what solved my problem in case you run into the issue as well. After three days of code rewrites, it was simply the plus sign that broke the rewrites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use only one line with Options:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
...
```

And I add `-MultiViews`.
You can read that: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#options

> Normally, if multiple Options could apply to a directory, then the
>   most specific one is used and others are ignored; the options are not
>   merged. (See how sections are merged.) However if all the options on
>   the Options directive are preceded by a + or - symbol, the options are
>   merged. Any options preceded by a + are added to the options currently
>   in force, and any options preceded by a - are removed from the options
>   currently in force.

Comment: You solved the problem. I created the htaccess file based on your syntax and it is functioning correctly. (http://naberbiology.com/)
Thank you for the insight. Much appreciated!